# Display orders on client dashboard page

Tags: orders, dashboard

I'm creating a Magento template from scratch using the Base package as, well... the base.

I've customized the **dashboard.phtml** file to display a **collapsible accordion** where each panel displays a user's given profile data.

One of these panels is supposed to **display the client's order history** instead of displaying it on a separate page. So I figure I need to customize the **orders.phtml** file and call it into the dashboard.phtml file.

The problems i'm having are the following :

1. I can't figure out which layout file handles this kind of change.
2. I'm unsure if there is anything that needs to be done to avoid the order history page from being accessed directly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

this code will show you block to `account dashboard`

```
 <customer_account_index>
            <reference name="my.account.wrapper" >
                <block type="modulename/blockname" name="test123" after="-" template="test/order.phtml"
                    />
            </reference>

        </customer_account_index>
```